# How to make a key-locked wall?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure game in Minecraft and I am currently making an ocean monument level. I want to make it so that when you go and get a key and click a block, a few holes open in a 3x3 wall, but not enough to walk through. And when you get a second key and click a second block, more holes open, enough for you to walk through.

However, I am not sure how to achieve this. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have two solutions for you:

The first one tests if there is a specific item within a particular area, In this case, I gave myself a paper with the tag `Key:1`:

```
/give @p paper{Key:1} 1
```

I can then put this in a repeating command block to test for the paper:

```
/execute at @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{Key:1}}},x=4,y=56,z=9,dx=1,dy=1,dz=1] run say ok
```

In this case, it looks for the specific item at 4 56 9, in an area of the size 1 in all directions making it the size of 1 block.

You can change the `at` to `as` or `if entity` as you wish, it doesn't seem to make a difference except for when I use `as` in this command, it says `"[Paper] ok"` instead of `"[@] ok"`.

You would then replace the coordinates to your desired block, like under a sign that says `"Throw key here!"`, or something.

You can then change the tag to whatever, I named it `Key:1` but you can use anything as long as you use a colon `:` in it and always test for the same as you named it.

I recommend using `setblock` to place a Redstone block next to some command blocks for your desired effect.

You would then in a chain command block put this command to delete the paper:

```
/execute as @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{Key:1}}},x=4,y=56,z=9,dx=1,dy=1,dz=1] run kill @s
```

---

The other method would require the player to hold the key and press a button or maybe sign:

```
/execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{Key:1}}}] run say hi
```

This command tests for all players holding a paper with the tag `Key:1`.

You would do the same as the first but with the use of a button, and then put this command in the chain block:

```
/execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:paper",Count:1b,tag:{Key:1}}}] run clear @s paper{Key:1}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to do this exactly but if you use an observer and a sticky piston you should be able to do it. It would just be easier to cheat with. Unless you know how to do commands then you should be able to program it to open it if there is a specific item in the area of the coordinates.

Comment: sorry, then I do not know what to do then.

Comment: This is a pretty vague answer...